# Creating Line2D object

Tags: java, swing

I want to create Line using `Line2D` class, but when I run my class I receive this:

> Linia: java.awt.geom.Line2D$Double@15db9742.

Here is my code:

```
class linia {

    public java.awt.geom.Line2D.Double getLine() {
        return line;
    }

    public void setLine(java.awt.geom.Line2D.Double line) {
        this.line = line;
    }
    private java.awt.geom.Line2D.Double line;

}

public class Lines {

    public static java.awt.geom.Line2D.Double create(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
        java.awt.geom.Line2D.Double tmpL = new java.awt.geom.Line2D.Double();
        tmpL.x1 = x1;
        tmpL.y1 = y1;
        tmpL.x2 = x2;
        tmpL.y2 = y2;
        return tmpL;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        linia line = new linia();
        line.setLine(create(Double.valueOf(1), Double.valueOf(1), Double.valueOf(2), Double.valueOf(2)));
        System.out.println("Line: " + line.getLine());
    }

}
```

Comment: What did you expect this to print out?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have no default constructor in the **linia** class. Another option is to add custom constructor based on the parameters and any initialization required.

Java requires a constructor in any class definition.

```
class Linia
{
     public Linia() {
        // here you add any default implementation required
     }

    public java.awt.geom.Line2D.Double getLine() {
        return line;
    }
    public void setLine(java.awt.geom.Line2D.Double line)
    {
        this.line = line;
    }
}
```

Note: the naming convention in Java prefers that Java class will start with capital letter, hence it is a good practice to call you class **Linia** and not **linia**.

Answer (score 0):

You can print the coordinates of the line using `getBounds()` method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     linia line = new linia();
     line.setLine(create(Double.valueOf(1), Double.valueOf(1), Double.valueOf(2), Double.valueOf(2)));
     System.out.println("Line: " + line.getLine().getBounds());
}
```

Expected output:

```
Line: java.awt.Rectangle[x=1,y=1,width=1,height=1]
```